# Mostrar y ocultar información AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estoy intentando mostrar un contenido si le doy click a un titulo y volverlo a ocultar si le vuelvo a dar click, estoy haciendo uso del ng-if, si retiro la linea de `$scope.varShowHide =! $scope.varShowHide;` obviamente si me muestra el contenido, pero quiero que se vuelva a ocultar.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body>

        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
            <div ng-click="exampleShowHide()">
                <h1>mostrar y ocultar informacion</h1>                
            </div>
            <div ng-if="varShowHide">ACA VA EL TEXTO A MOSTRAR POR EJEMPLO UN ANIMAL O UNA FRUTA</div>

        </div>

        <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

            $scope.exampleShowHide = function(){
                $scope.varShowHide = true;
                $scope.varShowHide =! $scope.varShowHide;
            }
        });
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Debes declarar tu variable `$scope.varShowHide` fuera de la función `$scope.exampleShowHide` ya que al declararla adentro con valor de `true` y luego asignarle el valor contrario siempre estaría quedando en `false`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body>

        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
            <div ng-click="exampleShowHide()">
                <h1>mostrar y ocultar informacion</h1>                
            </div>
            <div ng-if="varShowHide">ACA VA EL TEXTO A MOSTRAR POR EJEMPLO UN ANIMAL O UNA FRUTA</div>

        </div>

        <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.varShowHide = true;
            
            $scope.exampleShowHide = function(){
                $scope.varShowHide =! $scope.varShowHide;
            }
        });
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Es bueno aclarar que `ngIf` crea un child scope que seria innecesario para este escenario. Recomendaría utilizar `ngShow`.